# Namespace related error in VS 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, namespaces

I'm in a big trouble as in my project, suddenly designer.cs files are not loading and a  Namespace related error is shown.

[image]

When I double click on a designer in solution explorer following error window appears.

[image]

I checked all the references are there in the reference section So I have no idea whats has happened. Its completely sudden!  Highly appreciate your help in this regard...

Comment: Please post code and error messages as text, not screenshots.

Comment: what are the error messages?

Comment: Its not a single error. lots of errors everywhere telling some components are not found. This error began to occur after the finally added class to solution. So removed that class and now seems its ok. no errors. ridiculous!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed the newly added class from the solution (a simple class with few properties) guessing some thing may be wrong with it as every thing started after adding that class. And now the solution is not giving any errors its compiling.

I wonder why adding a class may lead to such problems in the IDE!

Answer (score 2):

This issue comes not because of any missing reference. The same error you can reproduce by creating a simple `Windows Form` and add the `Form1_Load` event in the code behind and delete. This issue will raise because the `Designer.cs` file still have a reference to this event. Inorder to get back your UI, needs to delete the event handling line from `cs` file.

Now let's come to your problem, go to the `Designer.cs` file of your `Window` and delete the below line of code.

```
this.dtpAdvanceDate.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
```

Comment: I removed the newly added class from the solution and now its not giving any errors. I had only added a class and had some properties in it. Do you have any idea what caused this problem?